# Combine 2 datasets in R with different range intervals to create a new dataset with ranges that account for overlap within the original datasets

Tags: r, excel, range

I have two datasets. Dataset 1 contains columns with `range start`, `range end`, and `variable Y`. Dataset 2 contains columns with `range start`, `range end`, `variable A`, `variable B`, and `variable C`.

I want to compare the two sets of ranges in the two Datasets and create a new dataset that has the range overlaps in two columns (i.e. start range overlap, end range overlap) and the all the variables of this overlap (i.e. `variable Y`, `variable A`, `variable B`, `variable C`)

I am very new to R so I am a bit confused as to how to go about this or even to explain it properly but here is an example that I think will explain it.

```
Dataset 1:
Start range (96.98, 97.02, 97.06)
End range (97.005, 97.05, 97.095)
Variable Y (1.48, 0.42, 4.78)
```

[image]

```
Dataset 2:
start range(96.95, 97, 97.05)
end range(97, 97.05, 97.1)
Variable A (100, 50, 10)
Variable B (0, 30, 30)
```

[image]

```
New Dataset 3:
Start range (96.95, 96.98, 97, 97.005, 97.02, 97.05, 97.06, 97.095)
end range (96.98, 97, 97.005, 97.02, 97.05, 97.06, 97.095, 97.1)
Variable Y (NA, 1.48, 1.48, NA, 0.42, NA, 4.78, NA)
Variable A (100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 10, 10, 10)
Variable B (0, 0, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30)
```

[image]

*note NA is no value - in this case, I still want the columns that don't overlap to be included.

Answer (score 2):

If you just wanted the overlapping ranges, that would be easy: it could be written, for instance, as a SQL join, with `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("
  SELECT MAX(d1.start, d2.start) AS start,
         MIN(d1.end,   d2.end)   AS end,
         d1.start AS start1,
         d1.end   AS end1,
         d2.start AS start2,
         d2.end   AS end2,
         d1.Y, d2.A, d2.B, d2.C
  FROM d1, d2
  WHERE d1.start <= d2.end AND d2.start <= d1.end
")
```

If you also want the intervals on which there is no overlap, it is trickier;
in particular, a given interval could have several subintervals with no overlap.
One solution is to first compute all those subintervals, by gathering all the endpoints.

```
dates <- sort( unique( c( d1$start, d1$end, d2$start, d2$end ) ) )
d <- data.frame(
  start = dates[-length(dates)],
  end   = dates[-1]
)
t1 <- sqldf("
    SELECT d.start, d.end, d1.Y
    FROM d LEFT JOIN d1
    ON MAX(d.start, d1.start) < MIN(d.end, d1.end)
")
t2 <- sqldf("
    SELECT d.start, d.end, d2.A, d2.B, d2.C
    FROM d LEFT JOIN d2
    ON MAX(d.start, d2.start) < MIN(d.end, d2.end)
")
sqldf( "SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (start, end)" )
```

Sample data used:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
  start = c(96.98, 97.02, 97.06),
  end   = c(97.005, 97.05, 97.095),
  Y     = c(1.48, 0.42, 4.78)
)
d2 <- data.frame(
  start = c(96.95, 97, 97.05),
  end   = c(97, 97.05, 97.1),
  A     = c(100,0,0),
  B     = c(0,0,0),
  C     = c(0,100,100)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment - however I was unable to load the library sqldf to try this the error message for library(sqldf) says: dependency 'RSQLite.extfuns' is not available. I then tried to load RSQLite.extfuns however it says that it is not available for my version of Rstudio.... I am currently running Version 1.2.1335   do you know how I can load it? thanks

Comment: The `RSQLite.extfuns` package is no longer a dependency of `sqldf`.
You can try to re-install `RSQLite` and `sqldf`:
having recent versions of them may make the problem disappear.
(If the problem persists, you can ask a new question, also providing the operating system and the version of R you use, as returned by `R.version`.)

Comment: Note that the last 3 sql statements could be written in one `sqldf` call using `with` like this: `sqldf("with t1 as (select ...), t2 as (select ...) select ...")`